# If oversampling didn't work?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, random-forest, resampling, oversampling

I use oversampling on my imbalanced training set but the estimator from model fitting cannot work on test set, i.e. the estimator classify all test data point as the majority class. In this case, the oversampling lose functionality and what did it mean: the dataset cannot be use to predict the target classes and I should give up?

Please advice. Cheers

```
train,test=train_test_split(data, test_size=0.25, stratify=y)

# Oversampling on class 1

df=train

index=df['Bad'] == 1

dup = df[index]

df = df.append([dup]*17, ignore_index=False)

train=df

X_train=train[cols] # [cols] defined previously 
y_train=train['Bad']

X_test=test[cols]
y_test=test['Bad']  

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,oob_score=True) 


results=rf.fit(X_train,np.ravel(y_train))     

confusion_matrix(y_test, results.predict(X_test))
```

Then I get the confusion matrix like:

[image]

Comment: Since you're using Python, the following may be of use to you, "Ajinkya More | Resampling techniques and other strategies": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z1PaqYKC1w&t=267s

Comment: @Jon Highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with another classifier, like Naive Bayes? Intuitively I can't really see how oversampling wouldn't work for the decision tree family of algorithms. At least not without pruning, which I'm unsure whether RandomForestClassifier does unless you tell it to. If you have to use decision trees, see what types of pruning you can do. Also, look up whether you can add a loss function to rf.fit to penalize misclassifictions of the minority class.

Comment: @Joje, very good point and I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Oh, that was supposed to be "Intuitively I can't really see how oversampling WOULD work for the decision tree family of algorithms." but I think my point got through anyway :)

Comment: For what reason do you want to perform oversampling?